# How would you use a cURL "GET" with a Python based REST API for network programming?

Tags: python, rest, python-2.7, curl, pycurl

Let me begin by saying I am a novice with `cURL`, `Python` and `REST`.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a virtual network with an SDN controller (Contrail). Contrail has a **Python based REST API** to allow for network automation development and management.

To access this `REST` API I have been trying to use `cURL` scripts temporarily through a Firefox extension, "RESTClient" just to make sure the cURL calls work independently from `Python`.

The cURL scripts are intended to query the VNs (virtual networks) and print out their information so that I can input IDs of the specific VNs that I need to remove as part of maintenance.

Here are the `cURL` scripts I'm currently working with:

**Request:**

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" http://10.xx.xx.xx:1234/virtual-networks
```

**Response (without values):**

```
{"virtual-networks": [{"href": , "fq_name": , ["default-domain", "vn-blue"], "uuid"}
```

.

Essentially, I want to be able to run the cURL script above in Python. I have Python 2.7, urllib2, libcurl, and pycurl set up, I just can't figure out the right syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can install the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library, you can use:

```
response = requests.get('http://10.xx.xx.xx:1234/virtual-networks')
response.json
```

You can set the header of the request with:

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.get('http://10.xx.xx.xx:1234/virtual-networks', headers=headers)
```

However you should only define `Content-type` for POST, PUT, PATCH requests, and use `Accept`for a GET.

Comment: Thanks Greg! I'll look into that library.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you want to craft a special HTTP request using `urllib2`, or -- some might consider this much better -- the 3rd party [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module. A HTTP request is not a too complex thing, you first might want to read about HTTP requests in general (start at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) or even look at the newly released [RFC 723*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230))). In your curl invocation, you are setting certain header parameters (using the `-H` switch). You can easily reproduce these using request's `custom headers` function, documented here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers.

Comment: Appreciate the advice and reference material.